# SQL Query Not Loading No Error phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've seen several instances across the web of a people running a SQL query in phpmyadmin and experiencing the loading screen, but it never retrieving information. I'm experiencing a similar issue and have been unable to find any solution.

**Here's the query:**

```
SELECT Comments.device_id, Comments.Author, Comments.Ack_type, 
Comments.Entry_Time, Comments.Comment_ID, Comments.Comment, 
History.datetime, History.device_status, History.status_name
FROM `Comments` LEFT JOIN History ON Comments.device_id = History.device_id
GROUP BY device_id
```

**Here are the issues:**

1. My apache2 and mysql error logs don't return any information. The Chrome console produces no errors for the elements on the page It just says loading.

[No Chrome Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqLET.png)

2. The phpmyadmin console doesn't error out but instead loads and locks down phpmyadmin

[phpmyadmin loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy5os.png)

3. Fails to ever return any information from the query.

**Things to note:**

Simple queries work and wrong queries produce error codes.

In order to get phpmyadmin running properly again after running this query I have to either clear my cookies, restart my web browser, or restart mysql on the server side.

**Here's the server information:**

- Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
- Server type: MySQL Server version:5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
- Protocol version: 10
- Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

**Here are the table structures:** 
[table structures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0lBe.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Try changing `GROUP BY device_id` to `GROUP BY Comments.device_id`
2. Try adding `LIMIT 1` to see if there is too many records

Comment: I changed the group by and added the limit and it is forever loading like earlier.

Is it possible it's something server side?

Comment: I have similar problem, simple select query returns nothing where as insert and update query working fine in phpmyadmin.

Comment: @Qmr Do you have tons of of data? Are you left joining two columns that are not indexed?